# Edit DataFrame to merge sub rows only

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe :

[image]

And I was wondering how to get :

[image]

As you can see blue rows are subrows and the idea is to group them together depending on the name :
I tried :

```
DFTest= pd.read_excel("XXXXXXXXXXX/Test.xlsx")
DFTest.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

But This does delete the blank rows `(0,1,2,5,6,7)`.
How would I group subrows together and keep Blank rows as they are ?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data as code in order to make helping you easier?

Comment: @albert I added the first line of the code  `pd.read`. `DFTest` is just a dataframe from an excel file (Picture 1). And the DF wanted would be Picture 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("Name", as_index = False)
df_sum = grouped_df.agg(np.sum)

pd.concat([df[df["Numb2"].isna()], df_sum])
```

Firstly I get the sum of all the values of the `Numb2` column and then concatenate this new dataframe with the rows that have an `NaN` value in the `Numb2` column.

This dataframe won't be the same as the one in the image you shared. But I don't think that'll be any problem.

But if is a problem then use the code below to get the dataframe sorted,

```
new_df.sort_values(by = "Name")
```

I hope this helped you!